# Updating destination table based on year-week and date comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-merge

I have two tables - source and destination, which are similar. They look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[srcTable](
    [Id] [INT] NULL,
    [Value] [INT] NULL,
    [QueryDate] [DATE] NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[destTable](
    [Id] [INT] NULL,
    [Value] [INT] NULL,
    [QueryDate] [DATE] NULL
)
```

I have the following data in these tables:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[srcTable]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[srcTable]
(
    [Id],
    [Value],
    [QueryDate]
)
SELECT 2, 3, '2023-01-03'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, '2023-03-03'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, '2023-03-02'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 6, '2023-03-04'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, '2023-03-17'


TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[destTable]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[destTable]
(
    [Id],
    [Value],
    [QueryDate]
)
SELECT 1, 2, '2023-03-03'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, '2023-03-10'
```

I want to always have the most recent QueryDate set in the [dbo].[destTable].

If there is a dataset in the [dbo].[srcTable] which matches the YearWeek of a dataset in the [dbo].[destTable], and the QueryDate of the source is **equal or greater** than the QueryDate of the destination, then the dataset for this YearWeek in the [dbo].[destTable] should be deleted and a new dataset should be inserted in the [dbo].[destTable] from the source table.

If there is no data in [dbo].[destTable] for a specific YearWeek, then the data is inserted in [dbo].[destTable] from the source.

The requirement is to group the data by YEAR-WEEK and also to compare the QueryDate column per week.

So, after running my query based on the data above, the [dbo].[destTable] will look like this:

```
SELECT 2, 3, '2023-01-03'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 6, '2023-03-04'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, '2023-03-10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, '2023-03-17'
```

I am trying to use a MERGE statement, but I am not sure how to delete the destination and insert at the same time when the data is matched. I tried this:

```
MERGE [dbo].[destTable] AS T  
USING (SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[srcTable] ) AS S 
ON CAST(YEAR(T.[QueryDate]) AS VARCHAR(4))  +'-' 
        +   CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, T.[QueryDate]) AS VARCHAR(2)) = CAST(YEAR(S.[QueryDate]) AS VARCHAR(4))  +'-' 
        +   CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, S.[QueryDate]) AS VARCHAR(2)) 
    
WHEN MATCHED AND S.[QueryDate] => T.[QueryDate] THEN 
   DELETE
   -- delete from target and insert again


WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  THEN 
   INSERT ([Id],
            [Value],
            [QueryDate]) 
    
    VALUES (S.[Id],
            S.[Value],
            S.[QueryDate])
;
```

Another idea is to spell out the logic to multiple deletes and inserts, nested in a loop for each distinct Year-Week in the source, but this seems long and clumsy. Is there a better way to make the MERGE statement work?

Comment: Delete + insert is the same as update, so why not just do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MERGE` cannot both delete and insert, as it cannot do multiple actions per target row. But you can just do an `UPDATE` instead.

You need to first filter the source data so that you only have one row per week. You can do that in a CTE.

```sql
WITH cte AS  (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATETRUNC(week, S.QueryDate) ORDER BY S.QueryDate DESC) AS rn
      FROM dbo.srcTable AS S
    ) S
    WHERE S.rn = 1
) 
MERGE dbo.destTable AS T
USING cte AS S
   ON DATETRUNC(week, S.QueryDate) = DATETRUNC(week, T.QueryDate)
WHEN MATCHED AND S.QueryDate >= T.QueryDate THEN
  UPDATE SET
    Id = S.Id,
    Value = S.Value,
    QueryDate = S.QueryDate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (Id, Value, QueryDate) 
  VALUES (S.Id, S.Value, S.QueryDate)
;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/thaVv1Ju)

Note that I've used `DATETRUNC(week` to compare by week, this is only available in SQL Server 2022. For older versions you can use a combination of `YEAR` and `DATEPART(week`.  See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5mh4ETKn).